# Can not get UserDetails in SecurityErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security

i want to get `UserDetails` from **HttpServletRequest** when I have **SessionAuthenticationException** - mean that session already exist for current use, but get null

My Hadnler is

```
public class SecurityErrorHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private static final String FORCE_PARAMETER_NAME = "force";

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //if session already exist
        if (exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(SessionAuthenticationException.class)) {
            logger.debug("Session already exist");
            Principal userPrincipal =  request.getUserPrincipal();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your security config? Are you using form login and do you need the username? There is no authentication set by spring security as session exceeded but you can get the requested username parameter based on what you submit on login

Comment: I have basic auth, so I get `UserDetails` when send request. But when I alredy have active session and login from another pc, I want to log it, so I need `UserDetails(or username)` in handler when have `SessionAuthenticationException`

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I did))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no easy way. You need to get it from `Authorization` header

```
    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    byte[] base64Token = 
              header.trim().substring(6).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] decoded = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Token);
    String token = new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    int delim = token.indexOf(":");
    String userName = token.substring(0, delim);
```

- The above code can look hacky but it is actually what spring security `BasicAuthenticationConverter` does. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationConverter.java#L94